# how to save a session, including unsaved changes to a file?

Tags: vim

expanding on the [use of vim sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642611/how-to-save-and-restore-multiple-different-sessions-in-vim), is there a way to also save dirty state (modified) of files?

Basically i need a way to just save everything as is and restore it later, as i do with some other IDEs.

Comment: :command -nargs=1 MySaveSession wa | mksession <args>